# Latest value for each timeperiod, person and category

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have tried browsing the problems & answers in this forum, but neither of them fit's my case sufficiently.

I have some people reporting in their status for 2 categories, which looks like this:

```
TimeStamp           | PersonID | Category | Value
2015-07-02 01:25:00 | 2303     | CatA     | 8.2
2015-07-02 01:25:00 | 2303     | CatB     | 10.1
2015-07-02 03:35:00 | 2303     | CatA     | 8.0
2015-07-02 03:35:00 | 2303     | CatB     | 9.9
2015-07-02 02:30:00 | 4307     | CatA     | 8.7
2015-07-02 02:30:00 | 4307     | CatB     | 12.7
.
.
.
2015-07-31 22:15:00 | 9011     | CatA     | 7.9
2015-07-31 22:15:00 | 9011     | CatB     | 8.9
```

Some people report status several times per hour, but others only a couple of times per day.

I need to produce an an output, which shows latest know status for each day, for each hour of the day, for each person and category. This should look like this:

```
Date        |Hour| Person | Category | Value
2015-07-02  | 1  | 2307   | CatA     | Null 
2015-07-02  | 1  | 2307   | CatB     | Null 
2015-07-02  | 2  | 2307   | CatA     | 8.2 
2015-07-02  | 2  | 2307   | CatB     | 10.2 
2015-07-02  | 3  | 2307   | CatA     | 8.2 
2015-07-02  | 3  | 2307   | CatB     | 10.2 
2015-07-02  | 4  | 2307   | CatA     | 8.0 
2015-07-02  | 4  | 2307   | CatB     | 9.9 
.
.
.
2015-07-31  | 23 | 9011   | CatA     | 7.9
2015-07-31  | 23 | 9011   | CatB     | 8.9
```

The first row(s) for each person and category will probably be null as there will be no known values as this is "beginning of time"

I have tried using a sub query like this:

```
SELECT Date
      ,hour
      ,Person
      ,Category
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 status FROM readings WHERE (readings.Date<=structure.Date) AND readings.Hour<=structure.hour)....and so forth.... order by TimeStamp DESC
FROM structure
```

This works - except in terms of performance because I need to do this for a month, for 2.000 persons for 2 categories and that means that the sub query must run (30*24*2000*2=2,880,000) times, and given the fact that table containing the readings also contains hundreds of thousands of readings, this don't work.

I have also tried messing round with row_number(), but have not succeed in this.

Any suggestions?

**Edit (19-10-2015 15:34)**: In my query example above I am referring to a "structure" table. This is actually just (for the time being) a view, with the following SQL:

```
SELECT Calendar.CalendarDay, Hours.Hour, Persons.Person, Categories.Category
FROM Calendar CROSS JOIN Hours CROSS JOIN Persons CROSS JOIN Categories
```

This in order to produce a table containing a row for each day, for each hour for each person and each category. This table then contains (30*24*2000*2=2,880,000) rows.

For each of these rows, I need to locate the latest status from the readings table. So for each Day, for each hour, for each person and each category I need to read the latest available status from the readings table.

Comment: try using  `Row_Number() Over()`

Comment: I don't understand the desired output. Shouldn't these be different persons?

Comment: Your question and desired output is unclear ...in query you are referring two tables..it will be good if you give us clear view of your tables  with sample data and desired output...

Comment: Thorsten: yes - the output should contain a record for each of the 2,000 persons, for each day, for each hour and category. Anwarr_hell: I have tried to explain a little further. The sample data and desired output is already there.

Comment: @ThomasPyndt see revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess.

Based on the task "to produce an output, which shows latest know status for each day, for each hour of the day, for each person and category" you need to take three steps:

(1) Find latest records for every hour;

(2) Get a table of all date and hours to show;

(3) Multiply that date-hours-table by persons and categories and left join the result with latest-records-for-every-hour.

```
-- Test data 

declare @t table ([Timestamp] datetime2(0), PersonId int, Category varchar(4), Value decimal(3,1));

insert into @t values
('2015-07-02 01:25:00', 2303, 'CatA', 8.2    ),
('2015-07-02 01:45:00', 2303, 'CatA', 9.9    ),
('2015-07-02 01:25:00', 2303, 'CatB', 10.1   ),
('2015-07-02 03:35:00', 2303, 'CatA', 8.0    ),
('2015-07-02 03:35:00', 2303, 'CatB', 9.9    ),
('2015-07-02 02:30:00', 4307, 'CatA', 8.7    ),
('2015-07-02 02:30:00', 4307, 'CatB', 12.7   );


-- Latest records for every hour 

declare @Latest table (
    [Date] date, 
    [Hour] tinyint, 
    PersonId int, 
    Category varchar(4), 
    Value decimal(3,1)

    primary key ([Date], [Hour], PersonId, Category)
);

insert into @Latest 
select top 1 with ties
    [Date]    = cast([Timestamp] as date),
    [Hour]    = datepart(hour, [Timestamp]),
    PersonId  ,
    Category  ,
    Value        
from
    @t
order by
    row_number() over(partition by cast([Timestamp] as date), datepart(hour, [Timestamp]), PersonId, Category order by [Timestamp] desc);


-- Date-hours table 

declare @FromDateTime datetime2(0);
declare @ToDateTime datetime2(0);

select @FromDateTime = min([Timestamp]), @ToDateTime = max([Timestamp]) from @t;

declare @DateDiff int = datediff(day, @FromDateTime, @ToDateTime);
declare @FromDate date = cast(@FromDateTime as date);
declare @FromHour int = datepart(hour, @FromDateTime);
declare @ToHour int = datepart(hour, @ToDateTime);

declare @DayHours table ([Date] date, [Hour] tinyint, primary key clustered ([Date], [Hour]) );


with N as 
(
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)    
),
D as (
    select
        row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1 as d
    from 
        N n1, N n2, N n3
),
H as (
    select top 24
        row_number() over(order by (select 1)) - 1 as h
    from 
        N n1, N n2
)
insert into @DayHours
select dateadd(day, d, @FromDate), h
from 
    D, h
where
    @FromHour <= (d * 100 + h) 
    and (d * 100 + h) <= (@DateDiff * 100 + @ToHour);


-- @PersonsIds & @Categories tables (just an imitation of the real tables)

declare @PersonsIds table (Id int primary key);
declare @Categories table (Category varchar(4) primary key);

insert into @PersonsIds select distinct PersonId from @t;
insert into @Categories select distinct Category from @t;


-- The result 

select
    dh.[Date],
    dh.[Hour],
    PersonId    =    p.Id,
    c.Category,
    l.Value
from
    @PersonsIds p cross join @Categories c cross join @DayHours dh
    left join @Latest l on l.[Date] = dh.[Date] and l.[Hour] = dh.[Hour] and l.PersonId = p.Id and l.Category = c.Category
order by
    [Date], [Hour], PersonId, Category;
```

**Edit (1):**

OK.
In order to bring over the previous values to empty spaces,
let's replace the last *select* statement with this one:

```
select top 1 with ties
    dh.[Date],
    dh.[Hour],
    PersonId    =    p.Id,
    c.Category,
    l.Value
from
    @PersonsIds p cross join @Categories c cross join @DayHours dh
    left join @Latest l 
        on (l.[Date] = dh.[Date] and l.[Hour] <= dh.[Hour] or l.[Date] < dh.[Date])  
        and l.PersonId = p.Id and l.Category = c.Category
order by
    row_number() 
        over (partition by dh.[Date], dh.[Hour], p.Id, c.Category 
              order by l.[Date] desc, l.[Hour] desc);
```

**Edit (2):**
Let's try to collect the *Cartesian product* in temporary table with clustered index: PersonId, Category, [Date], [Hour].

And then update the table dragging non-changed values:

```
declare @Result table (
    [Date]      date, 
    [Hour]      tinyint, 
    PersonId    int, 
    Category    varchar(4), 
    Value       decimal(3,1)

    primary key (PersonId, Category, [Date], [Hour]) -- Important !!!
)


insert into @Result
select
    dh.[Date],
    dh.[Hour],
    PersonId    =    p.Id,
    c.Category,
    l.Value
from
    @PersonsIds p cross join @Categories c cross join @DayHours dh
    left join @Latest l on l.[Date] = dh.[Date] and l.[Hour] = dh.[Hour] and l.PersonId = p.Id and l.Category = c.Category
order by
    [Date], [Hour], PersonId, Category;



declare @PersonId   int;
declare @Category   varchar(4);
declare @Value decimal(3,1);

update @Result set  
    @Value = Value = isnull(Value, case when @PersonId = PersonId and @Category = Category then @Value end),
    @PersonId = PersonId,
    @Category = Category;
```

For yet better performance consider changing table variables with temporary tables and applying indexes in accordance with query plan recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do it exactly right. When running this code, the result for 25-07-02, 2nd hour of the day for person 2303 is Null, but there is a reading the first hour of the day, which should then be repeated in the 2nd hour of the day.

Comment: this works using your sample data, but when applying this to 2000 persons, 30 days, 24 hours and several hundred thousands status readings, the query has so far been running for 15 minutes without a single result line.

Answer (score 0):

If i got it correctly ..it should give you desired result.

```
select st.Date,
     case when hour =1 then NULL
          else hour 
          end as hour
      ,st.Person,st.Category,
      (select status from reading qualify row_number() over (partition by personid 
      order by status desc)=1)
      from structure;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in SQL, but it will be quite slow, because for every person, category, day and hour you will have to look for the latest entry for the person and category until then. Just think of the process: Pick a record in your big table, find all statuses until then, order them and find the latest thus and pick its value. And this will be done for every record in your big table.

You might be better of to simply retrieve all data with a program written in a programming language and collect the data with a control-break algorithm.

However, let's see how it's done in SQL.

One problem is SQL Server's poor date/time functions. We want to compare date plus hour, which would be easiest with strings in 'yyyymmddhh' format, e.g. '2015101923' < '2015102001'. In your big table you have date and hour and in your status table you have datetimes. Let's see how we can get the desired strings:

```
convert(varchar(8), bigtable.calendarday, 112) +
right('0' + convert(varchar(2), bigtable.hour), 2)
```

and

```
convert(varchar(8), status.timestamp, 112) + 
right('0' + convert(varchar(2), datepart(hour, status.timestamp)), 2)
```

As this is - along with person and category - our key criterion to find records, you may want to have it as computed columns and add indexes (person + category + dayhourkey) in both tables.

You'd select from your big table and get the status value in a subquery. In order to get the latest matching record, you'd order by timestamp and limit to 1 record.

```
select 
  personid,
  calendarday,
  hour,
  category,
  (
    select value
    from status s
    where s.personid = b.personid
      and s.category = b.category
      and convert(varchar(8), s.timestamp, 112) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), datepart(hour, s.timestamp)), 2) <=
          convert(varchar(8), b.calendarday, 112) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), b.hour), 2)
    order by s.timestamp desc limit 1
  ) as value
from bigtable b;
```